# JSON stringify converts 0 to null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to convert my object to JSON but it doesn't convert my enum to 0. When I print the enum I get 0 but when I use inside the object it becomes null. If I use string, instead of integer it works.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var ItemStatus = {
        'Prepared': 0,
        'Ongoing': 1,
        'Finished': 2
    };
    module.exports = ItemStatus;
})();

(function () {
    'use strict';
    var ItemStatus = require('./itemstatus');

    function ItemDetail(detail) {
        detail = detail || {};

        this.message = detail.message || null;
        this.location = detail.location || null;
        this.status = detail.status || null;
        this.date = detail.date || null;

    }

    module.exports = ItemDetail;
})();

(function () {
    'use strict';

    var ItemDetail = require('./itemdetail');
    var ItemStatus = require('./itemstatus');

    function Item(item) {

        item = item || {}

        this.name = item.name || null;
        this.details = item.details || [];
        this.isFinished = item.isFinished || null;
        this.finishDate = item.finishDate || null;

    }

    Item.prototype.addDetail = function(message, location,date,status) {

        if (this.isFinished) {
            this.isFinished = false;
        }

        console.log('Status: ' + status); //Prints 0 correctly
        var detail = new ItemDetail({
            message: message,
            location: location,
            date:date,
            status:status

        });

        this.details.push(detail);
        if (status === ItemStatus.Finished) {
            this.isFinished = true;
            this.finishDate = date;
        }
    };


    module.exports = Item;
})();
```

Failing Test

```
var should = require('should');

var Item = require('../lib/models/item');
var ItemDetail = require('../lib/models/itemdetail');
var ItemStatus = require('../lib/models/itemstatus');


describe('Item Detail Test:', function() {
   this.enableTimeouts(false);


    var myItem = new Item({
        name: 'Something',
    });

    myItem.addDetail('Something happened','NY',1212122,ItemStatus.Prepared);
    myItem.addDetail('Another thing','NY',1412122,ItemStatus.Ongoing);
    myItem.addDetail('It is done','NY',1212122,ItemStatus.Finished);


    it('should print JSON', function() {
        myItem.name.should.eql('Something');
        console.log(myItem.details[0].status);
        myItem.details[0].status.should.eql(ItemStatus.Prepared);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myItem));
    });
});
```

When printed my Item shows the following

```
{"name":"Something","details":[{"message":"Something happened","location":"NY","status":null,"date":1212122},{"message":"Another thing","location":"NY","status":1,"date":1412122},{"message":"It is done","location":"NY","status":2,"date":1212122}],"isFinished":true,"finishDate":1212122}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(myItem);` shows?

Comment: It prints null for the first detail's status. I added console log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You problem is not related to *JSON stringify* .

The line `this.status = detail.status || null;` converts the `0` to `null`.
Because `0` is falsy your `this.status` will be set to `null` for `detail.status` being `0`.

You can solve this problem by either starting your *ItemStatus* with `1` or not using `this.status = detail.status || null;`

So either use:

```
var ItemStatus = {
    'Prepared': 1,
    'Ongoing': 2,
    'Finished': 3
};
```

Or do your test this way:

```
this.status = detail.status;
if( this.status !== 0 && !this.status) {
  this.status = null;
}
```

Comment: Argh, exactly that was what i am going to write. :D

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Null is there for the case in which when status is not supplied, it should print null. If I remove || null part it will work with 0 but when I supply ```ItemStatus.DontExist```, it will not print the status part in JSON.

Comment: @Meanteacher then use `'Prepared': 1, 'Ongoing': 2, 'Finished': 3`, if this is possible. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call:

```
this.status = detail.status;
```

Because, if detail.status is not defined, it is null, so `|| null` is needed.

Comment: The actual problem is when it is set to `'Prepared': 0,` .  The test is `myItem.details[0].status.should.eql(ItemStatus.Prepared);`. It is a general pitfall when  staring the elements in an _enum_ like object with `0` instead of `1`.